# cursor.fetchall() returns only default value of function's cursor (not running fetch all in)

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am having a little bit of a trouble trying to pull my data through a function I've created in my database (using postgresql + postgis). The case is, whenever I run my query, which can be found in my function via sql, separately, it runs just fine and returns my data.

My function looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION common.myfunc(string) RETURNS refcursor AS 
    $BODY$ 
    DECLARE
         ref refcursor default 'outrefcursor' 
    BEGIN
         OPEN ref FOR

         -- pretty big query here

         RETURN ref; END;
    $BODY$   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

When I run

```
SELECT common.myfunc(string);
FETCH ALL IN outrefcursor;
```

It works just fine

However, on my django side when I do

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM common.myfunc(someString)")
mydata = cursor.fetchall()
```

it return the default value of the cursor 
[image: fetchall() behavior]

I'd truly appreciate any help to solve this strange behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. The deal is: if you need to run a sql function and then `fetch all in cursor`, you have to do it explicitly and atomically.

For example,

You run your function

```
SELECT common.myfunc(string);
FETCH ALL IN outrefcursor;
```

First, django's `cursor.fetchall()` won't do the `FETCH ALL IN ---` for you. It has to be explicit as a command. However, if you run `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM common.myfunc(someString)")`, django will automatically commit this command and lose track of the cursor it got returned from the query. The trick is to wrap your view with `@transaction.atomic`

Follows the example,

```
@transaction.atomic
def func(request):
cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT myfunc('"+ parameter +"')")
        cursor.execute('FETCH ALL IN "outrefcursor"')
        data = cursor.fetchall()
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```